# Error while creating an object of an other class in a class of type Thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

Level: Beginner

I am using python v2.7 and wxPython v3.0 on windows 7 32-bit.

**My app**: I have 3 classes. One class is `gui(wx.Frame)` and other is `TestThread(Thread)` and the third is `labels()`.

**Problem**: I am trying to create an object of the `gui(wx.Frame)` class in `TestThread(Thread)` class, but I am getting an error as given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\post.py", line 11, in <module>
    class TestThread(Thread):
  File "C:\test\post.py", line 12, in TestThread
    guiObj = gui()
NameError: name 'gui' is not defined
```

However if I try to call the `createPanels()` of `gui(wx.Frame)` class from the `TestThread(Thread)` class like this  `wx.CallAfter(gui().createPanels())` then I get following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\test\post.py", line 24, in run
    wx.CallAfter(gui().createPanels())
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

I think the reason is something related to the `__init__()` of the `gui(wx.Frame)`
I didn't understand the reason.

**Update:** I tried to create an object of `labels()` class in `TestThread(Thread)` class, I get the same error as shown in first case above. Is there something special about this `TestThread(Thread)` class?

The complete code is provided below and can be [downloaded here](https://db.tt/ZjqgqJwH) to avoid identation problems:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from random import randrange
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
from threading import Thread
from wx.lib.pubsub import setuparg1
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub as Publisher
##################################################
class TestThread(Thread):
     guiObj = gui()

     def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()    # start the thread

     def run(self):
        wx.CallAfter(guiObj.createPanels())
        time.sleep(5)

##############################################
class gui(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        screenWidth = 800
        screenHeight = 450
        screenSize = (screenWidth, screenHeight)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=screenSize)
        self.locationFont = locationFont = wx.Font(15, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer = sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.panel = panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        panel.SetupScrolling()
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFF')
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        mainSizer.Add(panel, 15, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    def createPanels(self):
       k = 0
       labelObj = labels()
       locations = labelObj.getLabel()
       print locations
       for i in locations:
           sPanels = 'sPanel'+str(k)
           sPanels = wx.Panel(self.panel)
           label = str(k+1)
           text = wx.StaticText(sPanels, -1, label0)
           text.SetFont(self.locationFont)
           text.SetForegroundColour('#0101DF')
           self.sizer.Add(sPanels, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
           self.sizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(self.panel), 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 0)
           k += 1

   TestThread()
################################################
class labels():
    def getLabel(self):
       mylist =[]
       i = randrange(10)
       for k in range(1,i+1):
           mylist.append(k)
       return mylist
###############################################

if __name__=='__main__':
   app = wx.App()
   frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
   frame.Show()
   app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first issue:**

`guiObj = gui()` is executed when Python first runs the file, which causes two problems:

- Python does not know about `gui` when executing it
- All instances of `TestThread` will have the same `gui` instance

To fix both of them, you have to put `guiObj = gui()` in the constructor of `TestThread`

If you only want to fix the first one, put the declaration of `gui` before the declaration of `TestThread`.

**For the second issue:**

Using `gui()` is wrong because the constructor of `gui` takes three arguments (four actually, but the first one is implicit. You have to call it with three arguments, like you did at the end of the program: `gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")`

Comment: I have put the guiObj = gui() in the constructor of TestThread and also put the declaration of gui() before TestThread(). Now I get error that: 
NameError: name 'TestThread' is not defined

Comment: Why did you put `TestThread()` in the class declaration of `gui`, actually?

Comment: I am confused with the threading topic. I am just experimenting. Where do you suggest that TestThread() should be? I am trying to use TestThread class to use threading to create panels in my app using createPanels() of the gui class. I just wanted to see if it updates my gui without freezing/blocking. It seems to me that  I am not implementing it in a correct way!

Comment: You could do it in the main